# How to factory reset a android sunrise

Tags: factory-reset, lg-sunrise

My Phone is an Lg Sunrise and it wont let me factory rest nor is the volume down and lock button working so what else could I do

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the correct drivers for your device, and install 15-second adb installer from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MKgCbUM0itNVB1elljU2NPR0k/view).
2. Right-click in your ADB folder (usually in root of C:) and open a command line and input the following:

   ```
   adb reboot bootloader
   ```
3. Check to see if the phone is in fastboot mode.

   ```
   fastboot devices
   ```
4. If it doesn't show anything, wait a few seconds and try again.
5. Wipe the user data/cache.

   ```
   fastboot -w
   ```